# How to define groups of required attributes in XSD?

Tags: attributes, xsd, requirements

Suppose I want element XXX can have either attribute AAA along with attribute BBB in pair or attribute CCC along with DDD in pair but never mix AAA with DDD or similiar.

How can I define this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not available functionality within xsd. If you want to restrict attributes to two groupings then you will need to define two elements, one for each of the attribute groupings. For example:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="MyType1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="AAA" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="DDD" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="MyType2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="BBB" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="CCC" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: But this gives two different element names. I want one name with 2 possibilities...

Comment: I understand what you want. What I am saying is that is not possible with XSD. You need to (and probably should) define two types.